# Получить IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER32 AddressOfEntryPoint из Assembly

Tags: c#, pe

Возможно ли такое на C#?
Нужно получить этот параметр

```
// IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER32:
// 000000A8 - 000000AB `Это->0000838E<-Это` = AddressOfEntryPoint
```

Если возможно, поделитесь статьей/туториалом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно взять класс PeHeaderReader [отсюда](https://gist.github.com/b0urb4k1/ef386f9075d1f74fdff607f306743954):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


/// <summary>
/// Reads in the header information of the Portable Executable format.
/// Provides information such as the date the assembly was compiled.
/// </summary>
public class PeHeaderReader
{
    #region File Header Structures

    public struct IMAGE_DOS_HEADER
    {      // DOS .EXE header
        public UInt16 e_magic;              // Magic number
        public UInt16 e_cblp;               // Bytes on last page of file
        public UInt16 e_cp;                 // Pages in file
        public UInt16 e_crlc;               // Relocations
        public UInt16 e_cparhdr;            // Size of header in paragraphs
        public UInt16 e_minalloc;           // Minimum extra paragraphs needed
        public UInt16 e_maxalloc;           // Maximum extra paragraphs needed
        public UInt16 e_ss;                 // Initial (relative) SS value
        public UInt16 e_sp;                 // Initial SP value
        public UInt16 e_csum;               // Checksum
        public UInt16 e_ip;                 // Initial IP value
        public UInt16 e_cs;                 // Initial (relative) CS value
        public UInt16 e_lfarlc;             // File address of relocation table
        public UInt16 e_ovno;               // Overlay number
        public UInt16 e_res_0;              // Reserved words
        public UInt16 e_res_1;              // Reserved words
        public UInt16 e_res_2;              // Reserved words
        public UInt16 e_res_3;              // Reserved words
        public UInt16 e_oemid;              // OEM identifier (for e_oeminfo)
        public UInt16 e_oeminfo;            // OEM information; e_oemid specific
        public UInt16 e_res2_0;             // Reserved words
        public UInt16 e_res2_1;             // Reserved words
        public UInt16 e_res2_2;             // Reserved words
        public UInt16 e_res2_3;             // Reserved words
        public UInt16 e_res2_4;             // Reserved words
        public UInt16 e_res2_5;             // Reserved words
        public UInt16 e_res2_6;             // Reserved words
        public UInt16 e_res2_7;             // Reserved words
        public UInt16 e_res2_8;             // Reserved words
        public UInt16 e_res2_9;             // Reserved words
        public UInt32 e_lfanew;             // File address of new exe header
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY
    {
        public UInt32 VirtualAddress;
        public UInt32 Size;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
    public struct IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER32
    {
        public UInt16 Magic;
        public Byte MajorLinkerVersion;
        public Byte MinorLinkerVersion;
        public UInt32 SizeOfCode;
        public UInt32 SizeOfInitializedData;
        public UInt32 SizeOfUninitializedData;
        public UInt32 AddressOfEntryPoint;
        public UInt32 BaseOfCode;
        public UInt32 BaseOfData;
        public UInt32 ImageBase;
        public UInt32 SectionAlignment;
        public UInt32 FileAlignment;
        public UInt16 MajorOperatingSystemVersion;
        public UInt16 MinorOperatingSystemVersion;
        public UInt16 MajorImageVersion;
        public UInt16 MinorImageVersion;
        public UInt16 MajorSubsystemVersion;
        public UInt16 MinorSubsystemVersion;
        public UInt32 Win32VersionValue;
        public UInt32 SizeOfImage;
        public UInt32 SizeOfHeaders;
        public UInt32 CheckSum;
        public UInt16 Subsystem;
        public UInt16 DllCharacteristics;
        public UInt32 SizeOfStackReserve;
        public UInt32 SizeOfStackCommit;
        public UInt32 SizeOfHeapReserve;
        public UInt32 SizeOfHeapCommit;
        public UInt32 LoaderFlags;
        public UInt32 NumberOfRvaAndSizes;

        public IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY ExportTable;
        public IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY ImportTable;
        public IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY ResourceTable;
        public IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY ExceptionTable;
        public IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY CertificateTable;
        public IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY BaseRelocationTable;
        public IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY Debug;
        public IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY Architecture;
        public IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY GlobalPtr;
        public IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY TLSTable;
        public IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY LoadConfigTable;
        public IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY BoundImport;
        public IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY IAT;
        public IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY DelayImportDescriptor;
        public IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY CLRRuntimeHeader;
        public IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY Reserved;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
    public struct IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER64
    {
        public UInt16 Magic;
        public Byte MajorLinkerVersion;
        public Byte MinorLinkerVersion;
        public UInt32 SizeOfCode;
        public UInt32 SizeOfInitializedData;
        public UInt32 SizeOfUninitializedData;
        public UInt32 AddressOfEntryPoint;
        public UInt32 BaseOfCode;
        public UInt64 ImageBase;
        public UInt32 SectionAlignment;
        public UInt32 FileAlignment;
        public UInt16 MajorOperatingSystemVersion;
        public UInt16 MinorOperatingSystemVersion;
        public UInt16 MajorImageVersion;
        public UInt16 MinorImageVersion;
        public UInt16 MajorSubsystemVersion;
        public UInt16 MinorSubsystemVersion;
        public UInt32 Win32VersionValue;
        public UInt32 SizeOfImage;
        public UInt32 SizeOfHeaders;
        public UInt32 CheckSum;
        public UInt16 Subsystem;
        public UInt16 DllCharacteristics;
        public UInt64 SizeOfStackReserve;
        public UInt64 SizeOfStackCommit;
        public UInt64 SizeOfHeapReserve;
        public UInt64 SizeOfHeapCommit;
        public UInt32 LoaderFlags;
        public UInt32 NumberOfRvaAndSizes;

        public IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY ExportTable;
        public IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY ImportTable;
        public IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY ResourceTable;
        public IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY ExceptionTable;
        public IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY CertificateTable;
        public IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY BaseRelocationTable;
        public IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY Debug;
        public IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY Architecture;
        public IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY GlobalPtr;
        public IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY TLSTable;
        public IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY LoadConfigTable;
        public IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY BoundImport;
        public IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY IAT;
        public IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY DelayImportDescriptor;
        public IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY CLRRuntimeHeader;
        public IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY Reserved;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
    public struct IMAGE_FILE_HEADER
    {
        public UInt16 Machine;
        public UInt16 NumberOfSections;
        public UInt32 TimeDateStamp;
        public UInt32 PointerToSymbolTable;
        public UInt32 NumberOfSymbols;
        public UInt16 SizeOfOptionalHeader;
        public UInt16 Characteristics;
    }

    // Grabbed the following 2 definitions from http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER.html

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    public struct IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 8)]
        public char[] Name;
        [FieldOffset(8)]
        public UInt32 VirtualSize;
        [FieldOffset(12)]
        public UInt32 VirtualAddress;
        [FieldOffset(16)]
        public UInt32 SizeOfRawData;
        [FieldOffset(20)]
        public UInt32 PointerToRawData;
        [FieldOffset(24)]
        public UInt32 PointerToRelocations;
        [FieldOffset(28)]
        public UInt32 PointerToLinenumbers;
        [FieldOffset(32)]
        public UInt16 NumberOfRelocations;
        [FieldOffset(34)]
        public UInt16 NumberOfLinenumbers;
        [FieldOffset(36)]
        public DataSectionFlags Characteristics;

        public string Section
        {
            get { return new string(Name); }
        }
    }

    [Flags]
    public enum DataSectionFlags : uint
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Reserved for future use.
        /// </summary>
        TypeReg = 0x00000000,
        /// <summary>
        /// Reserved for future use.
        /// </summary>
        TypeDsect = 0x00000001,
        /// <summary>
        /// Reserved for future use.
        /// </summary>
        TypeNoLoad = 0x00000002,
        /// <summary>
        /// Reserved for future use.
        /// </summary>
        TypeGroup = 0x00000004,
        /// <summary>
        /// The section should not be padded to the next boundary. This flag is obsolete and is replaced by IMAGE_SCN_ALIGN_1BYTES. This is valid only for object files.
        /// </summary>
        TypeNoPadded = 0x00000008,
        /// <summary>
        /// Reserved for future use.
        /// </summary>
        TypeCopy = 0x00000010,
        /// <summary>
        /// The section contains executable code.
        /// </summary>
        ContentCode = 0x00000020,
        /// <summary>
        /// The section contains initialized data.
        /// </summary>
        ContentInitializedData = 0x00000040,
        /// <summary>
        /// The section contains uninitialized data.
        /// </summary>
        ContentUninitializedData = 0x00000080,
        /// <summary>
        /// Reserved for future use.
        /// </summary>
        LinkOther = 0x00000100,
        /// <summary>
        /// The section contains comments or other information. The .drectve section has this type. This is valid for object files only.
        /// </summary>
        LinkInfo = 0x00000200,
        /// <summary>
        /// Reserved for future use.
        /// </summary>
        TypeOver = 0x00000400,
        /// <summary>
        /// The section will not become part of the image. This is valid only for object files.
        /// </summary>
        LinkRemove = 0x00000800,
        /// <summary>
        /// The section contains COMDAT data. For more information, see section 5.5.6, COMDAT Sections (Object Only). This is valid only for object files.
        /// </summary>
        LinkComDat = 0x00001000,
        /// <summary>
        /// Reset speculative exceptions handling bits in the TLB entries for this section.
        /// </summary>
        NoDeferSpecExceptions = 0x00004000,
        /// <summary>
        /// The section contains data referenced through the global pointer (GP).
        /// </summary>
        RelativeGP = 0x00008000,
        /// <summary>
        /// Reserved for future use.
        /// </summary>
        MemPurgeable = 0x00020000,
        /// <summary>
        /// Reserved for future use.
        /// </summary>
        Memory16Bit = 0x00020000,
        /// <summary>
        /// Reserved for future use.
        /// </summary>
        MemoryLocked = 0x00040000,
        /// <summary>
        /// Reserved for future use.
        /// </summary>
        MemoryPreload = 0x00080000,
        /// <summary>
        /// Align data on a 1-byte boundary. Valid only for object files.
        /// </summary>
        Align1Bytes = 0x00100000,
        /// <summary>
        /// Align data on a 2-byte boundary. Valid only for object files.
        /// </summary>
        Align2Bytes = 0x00200000,
        /// <summary>
        /// Align data on a 4-byte boundary. Valid only for object files.
        /// </summary>
        Align4Bytes = 0x00300000,
        /// <summary>
        /// Align data on an 8-byte boundary. Valid only for object files.
        /// </summary>
        Align8Bytes = 0x00400000,
        /// <summary>
        /// Align data on a 16-byte boundary. Valid only for object files.
        /// </summary>
        Align16Bytes = 0x00500000,
        /// <summary>
        /// Align data on a 32-byte boundary. Valid only for object files.
        /// </summary>
        Align32Bytes = 0x00600000,
        /// <summary>
        /// Align data on a 64-byte boundary. Valid only for object files.
        /// </summary>
        Align64Bytes = 0x00700000,
        /// <summary>
        /// Align data on a 128-byte boundary. Valid only for object files.
        /// </summary>
        Align128Bytes = 0x00800000,
        /// <summary>
        /// Align data on a 256-byte boundary. Valid only for object files.
        /// </summary>
        Align256Bytes = 0x00900000,
        /// <summary>
        /// Align data on a 512-byte boundary. Valid only for object files.
        /// </summary>
        Align512Bytes = 0x00A00000,
        /// <summary>
        /// Align data on a 1024-byte boundary. Valid only for object files.
        /// </summary>
        Align1024Bytes = 0x00B00000,
        /// <summary>
        /// Align data on a 2048-byte boundary. Valid only for object files.
        /// </summary>
        Align2048Bytes = 0x00C00000,
        /// <summary>
        /// Align data on a 4096-byte boundary. Valid only for object files.
        /// </summary>
        Align4096Bytes = 0x00D00000,
        /// <summary>
        /// Align data on an 8192-byte boundary. Valid only for object files.
        /// </summary>
        Align8192Bytes = 0x00E00000,
        /// <summary>
        /// The section contains extended relocations.
        /// </summary>
        LinkExtendedRelocationOverflow = 0x01000000,
        /// <summary>
        /// The section can be discarded as needed.
        /// </summary>
        MemoryDiscardable = 0x02000000,
        /// <summary>
        /// The section cannot be cached.
        /// </summary>
        MemoryNotCached = 0x04000000,
        /// <summary>
        /// The section is not pageable.
        /// </summary>
        MemoryNotPaged = 0x08000000,
        /// <summary>
        /// The section can be shared in memory.
        /// </summary>
        MemoryShared = 0x10000000,
        /// <summary>
        /// The section can be executed as code.
        /// </summary>
        MemoryExecute = 0x20000000,
        /// <summary>
        /// The section can be read.
        /// </summary>
        MemoryRead = 0x40000000,
        /// <summary>
        /// The section can be written to.
        /// </summary>
        MemoryWrite = 0x80000000
    }

    #endregion File Header Structures

    #region Private Fields

    /// <summary>
    /// The DOS header
    /// </summary>
    private IMAGE_DOS_HEADER dosHeader;
    /// <summary>
    /// The file header
    /// </summary>
    private IMAGE_FILE_HEADER fileHeader;
    /// <summary>
    /// Optional 32 bit file header 
    /// </summary>
    private IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER32 optionalHeader32;
    /// <summary>
    /// Optional 64 bit file header 
    /// </summary>
    private IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER64 optionalHeader64;
    /// <summary>
    /// Image Section headers. Number of sections is in the file header.
    /// </summary>
    private IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER[] imageSectionHeaders;

    #endregion Private Fields

    #region Public Methods

    public PeHeaderReader(string filePath)
    {
        // Read in the DLL or EXE and get the timestamp
        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(filePath, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read))
        {
            BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream);
            dosHeader = FromBinaryReader<IMAGE_DOS_HEADER>(reader);

            // Add 4 bytes to the offset
            stream.Seek(dosHeader.e_lfanew, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            UInt32 ntHeadersSignature = reader.ReadUInt32();
            fileHeader = FromBinaryReader<IMAGE_FILE_HEADER>(reader);
            if (this.Is32BitHeader)
            {
                optionalHeader32 = FromBinaryReader<IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER32>(reader);
            }
            else
            {
                optionalHeader64 = FromBinaryReader<IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER64>(reader);
            }

            imageSectionHeaders = new IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER[fileHeader.NumberOfSections];
            for (int headerNo = 0; headerNo < imageSectionHeaders.Length; ++headerNo)
            {
                imageSectionHeaders[headerNo] = FromBinaryReader<IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER>(reader);
            }

        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the header of the .NET assembly that called this function
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static PeHeaderReader GetCallingAssemblyHeader()
    {
        // Get the path to the calling assembly, which is the path to the
        // DLL or EXE that we want the time of
        string filePath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().Location;

        // Get and return the timestamp
        return new PeHeaderReader(filePath);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the header of the .NET assembly that called this function
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static PeHeaderReader GetAssemblyHeader()
    {
        // Get the path to the calling assembly, which is the path to the
        // DLL or EXE that we want the time of
        string filePath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(PeHeaderReader)).Location;

        // Get and return the timestamp
        return new PeHeaderReader(filePath);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Reads in a block from a file and converts it to the struct
    /// type specified by the template parameter
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="reader"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static T FromBinaryReader<T>(BinaryReader reader)
    {
        // Read in a byte array
        byte[] bytes = reader.ReadBytes(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T)));

        // Pin the managed memory while, copy it out the data, then unpin it
        GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(bytes, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        T theStructure = (T)Marshal.PtrToStructure(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), typeof(T));
        handle.Free();

        return theStructure;
    }

    #endregion Public Methods

    #region Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets if the file header is 32 bit or not
    /// </summary>
    public bool Is32BitHeader
    {
        get
        {
            UInt16 IMAGE_FILE_32BIT_MACHINE = 0x0100;
            return (IMAGE_FILE_32BIT_MACHINE & FileHeader.Characteristics) == IMAGE_FILE_32BIT_MACHINE;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the file header
    /// </summary>
    public IMAGE_FILE_HEADER FileHeader
    {
        get
        {
            return fileHeader;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the optional header
    /// </summary>
    public IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER32 OptionalHeader32
    {
        get
        {
            return optionalHeader32;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the optional header
    /// </summary>
    public IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER64 OptionalHeader64
    {
        get
        {
            return optionalHeader64;
        }
    }

    public IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER[] ImageSectionHeaders
    {
        get
        {
            return imageSectionHeaders;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the timestamp from the file header
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime TimeStamp
    {
        get
        {
            // Timestamp is a date offset from 1970
            DateTime returnValue = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);

            // Add in the number of seconds since 1970/1/1
            returnValue = returnValue.AddSeconds(fileHeader.TimeDateStamp);
            // Adjust to local timezone
            returnValue += TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.GetUtcOffset(returnValue);

            return returnValue;
        }
    }

    #endregion Properties
}
```

Использовать так:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly ass = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

PeHeaderReader reader = new PeHeaderReader(ass.ManifestModule.FullyQualifiedName);

if (reader.Is32BitHeader)
{    
    PeHeaderReader.IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER32 header32 = reader.OptionalHeader32;               
    uint address = header32.AddressOfEntryPoint;
}
else MessageBox.Show("not 32-bit header");
```

Comment: похоже из за того,что dll сделана под unity я не смогу получить header